# How to decode HTML Entities in C?

Tags: html, c

I'm interested in unescaping text for example: `&#x5c;` maps to `\` in C. Does anyone know of a good library?

As reference the Wikipedia [List of XML and HTML Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Answer (score 1):

For another open source reference in C to decoding these HTML entities you can check out the command line utility uni2ascii/ascii2uni. The relevant files are enttbl.{c,h} for entity lookup and putu8.c which down converts from UTF32 to UTF8.

[uni2ascii](http://billposer.org/Software/uni2ascii.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own unescape code; very simplified, but does the job: [pn_util.c](http://github.com/felipec/msn-pecan/blob/master/pn_util.c#L870)

Answer (score 0):

Function Description: Convert special HTML entities back to characters.
Need to do some modifications to fit your requirement.

```
char* HtmlSpecialChars_Decode(char* encodedHtmlSpecialEntities)
{
int encodedLen = 0;
int escapeArrayLen = 0;
static char decodedHtmlSpecialChars[TITLE_SIZE];
char innerHtmlSpecialEntities[MAX_CONFIG_ITEM_SIZE];

/* This mapping table can be extended if necessary. */
static const struct {
    const char* encodedEntity;
    const char decodedChar;
} entityToChars[] = {
        {"&lt;", '<'},
        {"&gt;", '>'},
        {"&amp;", '&'},
        {"&quot;", '"'},
        {"&#039;", '\''},
    };

if(strchr(encodedHtmlSpecialEntities, '&') == NULL)
    return encodedHtmlSpecialEntities;

memset(decodedHtmlSpecialChars, '\0', TITLE_SIZE);
memset(innerHtmlSpecialEntities, '\0', MAX_CONFIG_ITEM_SIZE);
escapeArrayLen = sizeof(entityToChars) / sizeof(entityToChars[0]);


strcpy(innerHtmlSpecialEntities, encodedHtmlSpecialEntities);
encodedLen = strlen(innerHtmlSpecialEntities);

for(int i = 0; i < encodedLen; i++)
{
    if(innerHtmlSpecialEntities[i] == '&')
    {
        /* Potential encode char. */
        char * tempEntities = innerHtmlSpecialEntities + i;

        for(int j = 0; j < escapeArrayLen; j++)
        {
            if(strncmp(tempEntities, entityToChars[j].encodedEntity, strlen(entityToChars[j].encodedEntity)) == 0)
            {
                int index = 0;
                strncat(decodedHtmlSpecialChars, innerHtmlSpecialEntities, i);

                index = strlen(decodedHtmlSpecialChars);
                decodedHtmlSpecialChars[index] = entityToChars[j].decodedChar;
                if(strlen(tempEntities) > strlen(entityToChars[j].encodedEntity))
                {
                    /* Not to the end, continue */
                    char temp[MAX_CONFIG_ITEM_SIZE] = {'\0'};
                    strcpy(temp, tempEntities + strlen(entityToChars[j].encodedEntity));
                    memset(innerHtmlSpecialEntities, '\0', MAX_CONFIG_ITEM_SIZE);
                    strcpy(innerHtmlSpecialEntities, temp);

                    encodedLen = strlen(innerHtmlSpecialEntities);
                    i = -1;
                }
                else
                    encodedLen = 0;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(encodedLen != 0)
    strcat(decodedHtmlSpecialChars, innerHtmlSpecialEntities);

return decodedHtmlSpecialChars;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
QString UNESC(const QString &txt) {
    QStringList bld;
    static QChar AMP = '&', SCL = ';';
    static QMap<QString, QString> dec = {
        {"&lt;", "<"}, {"&gt;", ">"}
      , {"&amp;", "&"}, {"&quot;", R"(")"}, {"&#039;", "'"} };

    if(!txt.contains(AMP)) { return txt; }

    int bgn = 0, pos = 0;
    while((pos = txt.indexOf(AMP, pos)) != -1) {
        int end = txt.indexOf(SCL, pos)+1;
        QString val = dec[txt.mid(pos, end - pos)];

        bld << txt.mid(bgn, pos - bgn);

        if(val.isEmpty()) {
            end = txt.indexOf(AMP, pos+1);
            bld << txt.mid(pos, end - pos);
        } else {
            bld << val;
        }// else // if(val.isEmpty())

        bgn = end; pos = end;
    }// while((pos = txt.indexOf(AMP, pos)) != -1)

    return bld.join(QString());
}// UNESC
```