# convert html entities to unicode(utf-8) strings in c?

Tags: html, c, unicode, html-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode HTML Entities in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082162/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-c)

This question is very similar to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python), but I need to do the same thing in C, not python. Here are some **examples** of what the function should do:

```
input    output

&lt;     <
&gt;     >
&auml;   ä
&#x00DF; ß
```

The function should have the signature char *html2str(char *html) or similar. I'm not reading byte by byte from a stream.

Is there a library function I can use?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you have html as one string or you are reading it one by one from stream?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a standard library function to do the job.  There must be a large number of implementation available in the Open Source world - just about any program that has to deal with HTML will have one.

There are two aspects to the problem:

1. Finding the HTML entities in the source string.
2. Inserting the appropriate replacement text in its place.

Since the shortest possible entity is '&x;' (but, AFAIK, they all use at least 2 characters between the ampersand and the semi-colon), you will always be shortening the string since the longest possible UTF-8 character representation is 4 bytes.  Hence, it is possible to edit in situ safely.

There's an illustration of HTML entity decoding in '[The Practice of Programming](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/)' by Kernighan and Pike, though it is done somewhat 'in passing'.  They use a tokenizer to recognize the entity, and a sorted table of entity names plus the replacement value so that they can use a binary search to identify the replacements.  This is only needed for the non-algorithmic entity names.  For entities encoded as 'ß', you use an algorithmic technique to decode them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `flex`.  Granted, flex is usually stream-based, but you can change that using the flex function `yy_scan_string` (or its relatives).  For details, see [The flex Manual: Scanning Strings](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html).

Flex's basic Unicode support is pretty bad, but if you don't mind coding in the bytes by hand, it could be a workaround.  There are probably other tools that can do what you want, as well.