# MySQL extract plaintext from html data or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

As the title, if I insert some html into the table. How can I use mysql to extract the plaintext between the html tags?
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`
(
  `id`    INT PRIMARY KEY,
  `plain` LONGTEXT
)
INSERT INTO `text` VALUES (1, '<p>text between tag 'p'</p><span>text between 'span'</span>');
```

And before insert, I want to use a trigger to extract the plain text I want. How to?
Or use php ? I mean pass the html to a php script and the php script does the extraction.

### update

Yet there's a solution for my problem by using php, how about the mysql one?

Comment: Try `strip_tags()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php with examples on that page.

Comment: thanx, i think it's the right way to do so :)

Comment: You're welcome. I would say so also, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your content always start with tags( etc.)**

try this:

```
SELECT * from table  WHERE colmn_name REGEXP  '>[^<]*mytext';
```

**Another way is to use `strip_tags` — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string**

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Output of above code:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

**Warning**::    `Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.`

You should put the html code in a variable, let's say `$html_input`

```
$html_input= "'<p>text between tag 'p'</p><span>text between 'span'</span>'";
$stripped_html = strip_tags($html_input);

// Now insert it into the table `text`
INSERT INTO `text` VALUES (1, $striped_html);
```

**Purely `MYSQL` way:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
LOOP
    SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
    IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
    SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
    IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
    SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
END LOOP;
END;

mysql> select strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hello world again.                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strip_tags()` function on the string, store the result in a variable, and then use that in your query:

```
$str = "'<p>text between tag 'p'</p><span>text between 'span'</span>'";
$str = strip_tags($str); //'text between tag 'p'text between 'span''
$str = mysql_real_escape_string($str); //just for safety
```

In your query:

```
INSERT INTO `text` VALUES (1, $str);
```

Documention: [**`strip_tags()`**](http://php.net/strip_tags), [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in MySQL itself too. Youd need a equivalent of the striptags php Funktion. Take a look here

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?656167-PHP-s-strip_tags()-equivalent-MYSQL-function

Answer (score 0):

Updating with some modifications from one of the above answers.

```
DELIMITER ***
                                CREATE FUNCTION ConvertHTMLToText(str LONGTEXT CHARSET utf8)
                                RETURNS LONGTEXT CHARSET utf8
                                BEGIN
                                DECLARE start, end INT DEFAULT 1;
                                    LOOP
                                    SET start = LOCATE("<", str, start);
                                    IF (!start) THEN RETURN str; END IF;
                                    SET end = LOCATE(">", str, start);
                                    IF (!end) THEN SET end = start; END IF;
                                    SET str = TRIM(INSERT(str, start, end - start + 1, ""));
                                END LOOP;
                            END ***
```

Comment: What does this do differently from the other answer?

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't like any of the existing solutions and I rolled my own that is ultra fast, removes HTML entities, too, and works on the MySQL server itself.

I've written this as a MySQL UDF in C so it can be as efficient as possible. I say "I've written" but it's basically just a mash of things that already existed, including the PHP `striptags` and `trim` functions straight from the PHP source code, and then the HTML entity decode function from here [How to decode HTML Entities in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082162/how-to-decode-html-entities-in-c).

The reason I didn't also port the PHP `htmlspecialchars_decode` function was simply that is was far too complicated for what I needed, with a lot of extra code for handling things like Big5 (Chinese) character encoding. If you need it to be as robust as PHP's `htmlspecialchars_decode`, then you might need to port it yourself, but so far my `unhtml` MySQL extension has proven very powerful for my use case.

You can download it here, and the install instructions are part of the gist.

```
//make sure libmysqlclient-dev is installed:
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

// Replace "/usr/lib/mysql/plugin" with your MySQL plugins directory (can be found by running "select @@plugin_dir;")
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql -o unhtml.so -shared unhtml.c -fPIC && cp unhtml.so /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/unhtml.so

//Then, on the server:
//create function`unhtml`returns string soname'unhtml.so';

//And use/test like:
select `unhtml`('<b>I&apos;ll say, it works!</b>');
```

https://gist.github.com/BrianLeishman/da6edb36ea2989b2ded533087e9d1511