# Searching readable text in field with HTML content using SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I've a SQL table containing HTML coded and formated text from a TinyMCE textarea field.

I want to give the frontend user of my PHP project the possibility to search for a record containing a special word.

If I use a clause like `WHERE description LIKE '%<word>%'`, the results (logicaly) also contains records with the word in the HTML code, not only in the readable text.

How I can search only the readable text in a field which contains HTML code?

Is there a function to filter out all unreadable code?

Comment: You can apply a `X_REG_REPLACE` on the column before you do the `LIKE`, this will probably perform very poorly though ;)

Comment: Please refer following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040097/mysql-extract-plaintext-from-html-data-or-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags